# How to prevent remove file operation on QNX?

Tags: fs, qnx

I faced with problem that I should prevent removing some applications from QNX device but I can't mount FS as read-only. So I tried to find some info about "interception" by resource manager remove operation, but it seems I can't do it. May be someone has any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of filesystem you use ??? and What is the version of your Qnx ???

Comment: What is the PC you use??? How you installed qnx on the board (cddisk, usbflash) ?? Give more info.

Comment: QNX Neutrino. All other stuff are variable.
Now I'm using beaglebone, qnx 6.6 and load system from uboot script

Comment: Alexandr, Did you solve your problem???

Comment: Oleg, no I don't find an answer

Comment: You boot from CompactFlash ???

Comment: As I said, It shouldn't be relevant for platform and devices for boot, It could be anything. For tests I'm using micro-sd card

Comment: @OlegGopkolov Have U some advices for me?